# Using java class from one package in main of another package (Same project)

Tags: java, eclipse, package

I have two packages inside a project I'm working on in Java and I need to call a class from one package when I run the main of a class in the other package.

I have something that looks like the following:

```
Project JavaCode
    /src
        /fr.insalyon.tc.framework
            Main.java
            Gameplay.java
        /Game
            Wythoff.java
```

and the problem is that in the Wythoff.java file I call `import fr.insalyon.tc.framework.Gameplay;` but I get an error when I run Main.java that says it cannot find the class Wthoff.

Main.java and Gameplay.java both have `package fr.insalyon.tc.framework;` as their first line, Gameplay is an interface and Wythoff implements Gameplay to play a game. What main does is the following:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( System.in ) );
nomClasse = in.readLine();
Class<?> votreClasse = Class.forName(nomClasse);  
JeuCombinatoire jeu = (JeuCombinatoire) votreClasse.newInstance();
```

and when I run Main and it prompts me to type the class name, typing Wythoff gives me a ClassNotFoundException

I don't know how to modify the project or packages to have this work together whilst keeping the current packages as they are, I don't want to have Wythoff.java in the default package, it needs to be in /Game

Comment: How do you execute your project? Do you use an IDE or is it by command line? In this case, what is your working directory and the command you use?

Comment: IDE eclipse (as indicated by the eclipse tag) and all I do is run Main.java which is in fr.insalyon.tc.framework

Comment: Do you input Wythoff or Game.Wythoff? Class.forName(param) - param needs to be fully qualified name of the desired class. Which line do you get the exception on?

Comment: Allowing/requiring user input to have _direct control_ over the specific Java class to be invoked seems a sketchy design choice, at best.  You may want to rethink this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Class.forName(nomClasse);` requires a full class name, as stated in [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName(java.lang.String)).

So you must type `Game.Wythoff`

Answer (score 1):

Class.forName(nomClasse); requires a fully Qualified path of  class name. Please change it nomClasse to (packgname.classname) & Improt Appropriat packages.

NOTE:- For More information read the Java Documentation 
Link:- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/

Answer (score 0):

You need to type either `fr.insalyon.tc.framework.Game.Wythoff` which is the fully qualified name.
alternatively in your case you can type also `Game.Wythoff` because the class which contains `main` method is in immediate parent package. And please note that normally package name starts with a simple letter for example `game` not `Game`.